# Read file in blocks with custom divider in python

Tags: python, block

How can I work with blocks easily from a txt file in python?

I would like to convert it to XML format.

What I already wrote ( It not shows the first TY rows...):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

sample = """
TY  - RPRT2
A1  - Peter
T1  - Something
ER  -

TY  - RPRT3
A1  - Peter2
T1  - Something else
ER  -

TY  - RPRT4
A1  - Peter3
T1  - Similar
ER  -
"""

def blocks2(text):
  """Only non-comment blocks *between* comments"""
  buff = []
  for line in text.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith('TY  -'):
      if buff:
        yield "\n".join(buff)
        buff = []
    else:
        buff.append(line)
  if buff:
   yield "\n".join(buff)

for block in blocks2(sample):
  print "Block:\n%s" % (block)
```

Comment: Did you actually write any python to attempt this yet?

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to paste.

Answer (score 0):

```
print sample.split("\n\n")
```

I think would work ...

or maybe

```
 filter(str.strip,map(lambda x:x.rsplit("TY -",1)[-1],sample.split("ER  -")))
```

Comment: But I need to check the blocks between "TY  -" and "ER  -". I would like to check syntax in this blocks, and if it's not okay, skip it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to process a txt file block per block withe following requirements :

- first line of a block has a prefix `TI -`
- last line is only `ER -`
- a block may contain lines with prefix `A1 -` or `T1 -`
- a block should not contain more than one line with each prefix.

You could use a condition variable to construct a dict. Assuming fd is a file object or a list of lines :

```
inbloc = False
for line in fd:
    if inbloc:
        if line.startswith('A1  -'):
            if 'A1' in bloc:
                inbloc = False
            else:
                bloc['A1'] = line[5:].strip()
        elif line.startswith('T1  -'):
            if 'T1' in bloc:
                inbloc = False
            else:
                bloc['T1'] = line[5:].strip()
        elif line.strip() == 'ER  -':
            # process bloc
            print (bloc)
        else:
            inbloc = False
    elif line.startswith('TY  -'):
        bloc = { 'TY' : line[5:].strip() }
```

With your `sample` string as input, this gives :

```
{'A1': 'Peter', 'T1': 'Something', 'TY': 'RPRT2'}
{'A1': 'Peter2', 'T1': 'Something else', 'TY': 'RPRT3'}
{'A1': 'Peter3', 'T1': 'Similar', 'TY': 'RPRT4'}
```